# Perl Text::CSV_XS read from string

Tags: string, perl, file, text, csv

How to I use the Text::CSV_XS module to read its input from a CSV string. Then only information I can find documented is reading from a file.

Would the fastest way to do it be splitting up the CSV string using the perl split function and reading each line from there or is there some built in method with Text::CSV_XS to read directly from a CSV string?

Thanks

Comment: The `parse` method looks like what you need: https://metacpan.org/module/Text::CSV#parse

Comment: What are you trying to do with one long CSV string ? This should be helpful for anyone who wants to answer.

Comment: The usage of `Text::CSV_XS` can be studied [here](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/Text-CSV_XS-0.95/CSV_XS.pm)

Comment: The perldoc for that module is quite long, but the method mentioned above (parse) is clearly mentioned in it. If you're coding in Perl, it's vital to get practice at reading the Perldoc.

Comment: Is the `parse` method not just used to parse one line of the CSV string?

Comment: Where has your string come from? Most often you would read it in from a file.

Comment: Lots of folks learn about slurp mod and then bias towards reading the entire file in one go, and then iterating over it in memory, ratehr than reading a line at a time.  I once worked at place that slurped multi-hundred-megabyte files, and would not (for political reasons) aloow me to rewrite them as line-at-a-time iterations so that we could transition from CGI to mod_perl.  sigh.

Answer (score 5):

The `getline` method of `Text::CSV_XS` will read from a file handle, so you can open the scalar string as a stream and pass that file handle.

This program demonstrates

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV_XS;

my $string = <<'END';
a,b,c,d
e,f,g,h
i,j,k,l
m,n,o,p
END


my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new;
open my $fh, '<', \$string;

while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
  print join('-', @$row), "\n";
}
```

**output**

```
a-b-c-d
e-f-g-h
i-j-k-l
m-n-o-p
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [parse](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV_XS#parse) method;

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

use Text::CSV_XS;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new();
if ( $csv->parse('Column1,Column2,Column2') ) {
    my @columns = $csv->fields;
    print Dumper( \@columns );
}
else {
    # Failed to parse the CSV data
}
```